# PTVS Python Script won't work

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm new in QGIS and python, using QGIS 2.14 Essen.
I'm wrote following script in QGis:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()

uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "dbName", "user", "pass")

uri.setDataSource("public", "shapes", "geom")
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "tbName", "postgres")

uri.setDataSource("public", "point", "geom")
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "tbName", "postgres")

processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation",{
                       "TARGET": layer2, 
                        "JOIN": layer1, 
                        "PREDICATE":u'intersects',
                        "SUMMARY":0,
                        "KEEP":0,
                       "OUTPUT":"path"})

vl = QgsVectorLayer("path", "name", "ogr")

saveUri = "dbname='dbname' host=localhost port=5432 user='user' password='pass' key=gid type=POINT table=\"public\".\"test\" (geom) sql="
crs_id = 4326
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs_id, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
error = QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer(vl, saveUri, "postgres", crs, False, False)
```

This script works well when run in QGIS, but i would like to run it from outside. When I am trying to write python script in PTVS, add:

```
imports 

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.setPrefixPath("path", True)
qgs.initQgis()

code..

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

First of all my processing.algList() contains only modeler: and grass: algorithms, second i can't connect to db. What should I do? Can I run the script from QGIS remotely?

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: Algorithm not found when use processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation" and Cannot connect in each line where try get or save to db. (Three times)